# After upgrding to com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0 I started geting this errors

Tags: android, firebase, build, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

After upgrding to

```
com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0
```

Cannot change dependencies of configuration ':app:api' after it has been included in dependency resolution.

Comment: which errors are you getting?

Comment: It is data binding that was causing the issue.